# Yii2 erro. Unknown Property – yii\base\UnknownPropertyException

Tags: yii

Boa noite,

Não consigo utilizar o software Yii a varios meses devido ao seguinte erro:

Unknown Property – yii\base\UnknownPropertyException
Getting unknown property: app\models\youSearch::E
1. in C:\xampp\htdocs\yii2basic\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Component.php 
at line 147

138
139
140
141
142
143
144
145
146
147
148
149
150
151
152
153
154
155
156
            if ($behavior->canGetProperty($name)) {
                return $behavior->$name;
            }
        }

```
    if (method_exists($this, 'set' . $name)) {
        throw new InvalidCallException('Getting write-only property: ' . get_class($this) . '::' . $name);
    }

    throw new UnknownPropertyException('Getting unknown property: ' . get_class($this) . '::' . $name);
}

/**
 * Sets the value of a component property.
 * This method will check in the following order and act accordingly:
 *
 *  - a property defined by a setter: set the property value
 *  - an event in the format of "on xyz": attach the handler to the event "xyz"
 *  - a behavior in the format of "as xyz": attach the behavior named as "xyz"
```

2. in C:\xampp\htdocs\yii2basic\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\BaseActiveRecord.php 
at line 286 
– yii\base\Component::__get('E') 
3. in C:\xampp\htdocs\yii2basic\models\youSearch.php 
at line 66 
– yii\db\BaseActiveRecord::__get('E')

60
61
62
63
64
65
66
67
68
69
70
        // grid filtering conditions
        $query->andFilterWhere([
            'id' => $this->id,
        ]);

```
    $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'Nome', $this->Nome])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'E-mail', $this->E-mail]);

    return $dataProvider;
}
```

}
4. in C:\xampp\htdocs\yii2basic\controllers\YouController.php 
at line 39 
– app\models\youSearch::search(['r' => 'you/index'])

33
34
35
36
37
38
39
40
41
42
43
44
45
     * Lists all you models.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $searchModel = new youSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

```
    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
```

5.

app\controllers\YouController::actionIndex() 
6. in C:\xampp\htdocs\yii2basic\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\InlineAction.php 
at line 57 
– call_user_func_array([app\controllers\YouController, 'actionIndex'], [])

51
52
53
54
55
56
57
58
59
        $args = $this->controller->bindActionParams($this, $params);
        Yii::trace('Running action: ' . get_class($this->controller) . '::' . $this->actionMethod . '()', **METHOD**);
        if (Yii::$app->requestedParams === null) {
            Yii::$app->requestedParams = $args;
        }

```
    return call_user_func_array([$this->controller, $this->actionMethod], $args);
}
```

}
7. in C:\xampp\htdocs\yii2basic\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Controller.php 
at line 156 
– yii\base\InlineAction::runWithParams(['r' => 'you/index'])

150
151
152
153
154
155
156
157
158
159
160
161
162
        }

```
    $result = null;

    if ($runAction && $this->beforeAction($action)) {
        // run the action
        $result = $action->runWithParams($params);

        $result = $this->afterAction($action, $result);

        // call afterAction on modules
        foreach ($modules as $module) {
            /* @var $module Module */
```

8. in C:\xampp\htdocs\yii2basic\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Module.php 
at line 523 
– yii\base\Controller::runAction('index', ['r' => 'you/index'])

517
518
519
520
521
522
523
524
525
526
527
528
529
        $parts = $this->createController($route);
        if (is_array($parts)) {
            /* @var $controller Controller */
            list($controller, $actionID) = $parts;
            $oldController = Yii::$app->controller;
            Yii::$app->controller = $controller;
            $result = $controller->runAction($actionID, $params);
            if ($oldController !== null) {
                Yii::$app->controller = $oldController;
            }

```
        return $result;
    }
```

9. in C:\xampp\htdocs\yii2basic\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Application.php 
at line 102 
– yii\base\Module::runAction('you/index', ['r' => 'you/index'])

96
97
98
99
100
101
102
103
104
105
106
107
108
            $params = $this->catchAll;
            unset($params[0]);
        }
        try {
            Yii::trace("Route requested: '$route'", **METHOD**);
            $this->requestedRoute = $route;
            $result = $this->runAction($route, $params);
            if ($result instanceof Response) {
                return $result;
            } else {
                $response = $this->getResponse();
                if ($result !== null) {
                    $response->data = $result;
10. in C:\xampp\htdocs\yii2basic\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php 
at line 380 
– yii\web\Application::handleRequest(yii\web\Request)

374
375
376
377
378
379
380
381
382
383
384
385
386
        try {

```
        $this->state = self::STATE_BEFORE_REQUEST;
        $this->trigger(self::EVENT_BEFORE_REQUEST);

        $this->state = self::STATE_HANDLING_REQUEST;
        $response = $this->handleRequest($this->getRequest());

        $this->state = self::STATE_AFTER_REQUEST;
        $this->trigger(self::EVENT_AFTER_REQUEST);

        $this->state = self::STATE_SENDING_RESPONSE;
        $response->send();
```

11. in C:\xampp\htdocs\yii2basic\web\index.php 
at line 12 
– yii\base\Application::run()

6
7
8
9
10
11
12

require(**DIR** . '/../vendor/autoload.php');
require(**DIR** . '/../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');

$config = require(**DIR** . '/../config/web.php');

(new yii\web\Application($config))->run();
$_GET = [
    'r' => 'you/index',
];

$_COOKIE = [
    '_csrf' => '3b5f68c032a757f50362118af4f7dbe99c4f8edb6c59634088c86586a0c773a5a:2:{i:0;s:5:"_csrf";i:1;s:32:"-8SgE6myM5wjc1W4Cr3fk4MlcCoJoVwk";}',
];

Podem me ajudar?

Comment: Por favor, edite esta pergunta porque está muito confusa. Faça um [Tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para aprender sobre como funciona este site e principalmente como fazer uma pergunta.